# How to create a div with optional overflow in Firefox

Tags: css, dom, overflow

I want to implement completion popup with CSS. Div which contains completion should have the following behavior:
- If size is smaller than (maxW x maxH), it should be sized to cover containing text
- If size is larger or equal than (maxW x maxH), it should have (maxW x maxH) size and have scrollbars.

I tried doing it this way:

Here's html:

```
<div class="main">
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>testtesttesttestteteetwew</div>
<div>test</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background: olive; 
}
```

However, it doesn't work the way I want it to. I always have scrollbars around div.
My example, doesn't work in Firefox.

You can experiment with this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/HjFCx/23/

Comment: please enclose a complete code example that reproduces the problem. it's hard to know what is wrong when you don't have all the facts.

Comment: Just a suggestion.... Try adding **`!important`** property.

Comment: @Yogesh Where should I do it? And how it works?

Comment: in order to incorporate some login, you're gonna have to, well, incorporate some logic. that is - CSS is not meant for conditionals, use JavaScript for that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BJsNa/  Seems to be working fine to me, all that isn't going to fit in a div that small. If you use less content, then it doesn't use scrollbars.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov your code is is working at my end. **`!important`** property can be used with `CSS` property to set highest important.... like `width : 100px !important` so width will not get override by any other subsequent `CSS`

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov I added a `min-width` and `min-height` and I didn't have any issues afterwards. Is this a solution or would it mess things up with something else in the page?

Comment: @Prospector It works well in chrome. However, it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: works fine for me in firefox

Answer (score 0):

What you have there works for me in Firefox, IE, and Chrome exactly as you have described, or at least as far as I understand it.  The div grows to fit the content unless it reaches the maximum height and width, at which point it gets scrollbars.

Comment: In firefox I can't get rid of empty scroller on the bottom (at least on OSX).

Comment: Maybe it's a version issue then.